# understanding coffeescript syntax

Tags: coffeescript

I'm new at CoffeeScript and I'm having trouble understanding some syntax of it.

For example, in this function call:

```
e('')
    .color('rgb(255,0,0)')
    .attr( x: 20,
           y: 100,
           w: 10,
           h: 100 )
```

I'm expecting this to compile JS code that passes an object with keys x, y, w, h to `attr` method. But this code actually compiles to this:

```
e('').color('rgb(255,0,0)').attr({
  x: 20
}, {
  y: 100,
  w: 10,
  h: 100
});
```

It's passing two objects to `attr`, first with key `x`, and second with keys `y`, `w`, and `h`. I'm having trouble understanding why is x separated from other keys, but other keys are not separated from each other?

Since I want to pass `attr` method one object, I tried this:

```
e('')
    .color('rgb(255,0,0)')
    .attr({x: 20,
           y: 100,
           w: 10,
           h: 100})
```

But this gives me that compile error in the line that `y: 100` gets place: `Error: Parse error on line 4: Unexpected '{'`. The strange thing is, there is no `{` in line 4. I also tried removing parens in `attr` but still got the same error.

I can solved it with this:

```
e('')
    .color('rgb(255,0,0)')
    .attr(
           x: 20,
           y: 100,
           w: 10,
           h: 100)
```

If I remove the newline after `.attr(`, then I'm getting the same code in my first example, which is not what I want.

Now I'm wondering if I'm misunderstanding some points in CoffeeScript syntax or there are really strange stuff in it. Or did I catch a bug in CoffeeScript? Any ideas?

I'm using CoffeeScript 1.3.1

Answer (score 3):

In coffeescript whitespace is significant. You can't just line things up whereever you think they should go. Try something like this:

```
e('')
  .color('rgb(255,0,0)')
  .attr(
    x: 20
    y: 100
    w: 10
    h: 100
  )
```

Edit: If you want to have x on the same line as the method call you just need to indent properly:

```
e('')
    .color('rgb(255,0,0)')
    .attr(x: 20,
    y: 100,
    w: 10,
    h: 100)
```

Comment: Hmm, so removing comma in object literals works. Thanks. I'm still looking for an answer of my compiler error and why only x is separated from other keys in my first example.

Comment: I believe the reason it got separated is because the first parameter was placed on the same line as the method call. And the newline makes the compiler assume a second set of variables. This assumption works well for methods with this kind of signature `methodName(param1, param2, objOrCallback)`

Comment: The reason why x is separated is because of the significant whitespace. You indented it wrong.

Comment: @Sandro, I'm not sure. `:` character is not valid in parameter syntax. It shouldn't be interpreted as a parameter.

Comment: Sure it's valid, it just means you're creating an object.

Comment: @david, well, other parameters have the same indentation too, why aren't the separated? If you mean one-character space before x, deleting it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: x is on a line with a single indent, the rest of the parameters an extra indent. I've edited the answer with another example.

Comment: @david, yes this indentation also works. But I still find it strange. Also I'm still looking for an answer of my compiler error.

Comment: The compiler error happens because you're indenting wrong. The reason it reports line 4 is because that's the point where it realises the `{` makes no sense after it encounters your extra indentation.

Comment: @david is correct. The inconsistent whitespace is what caused the separation of variables, not the fact that the you had a newline as I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for:

```
e('')
  .color('rgb(255,0,0)')
  .attr
    x:20
    y:100
    w:10
    h:100
```

which compiles to:

```
e('').color('rgb(255,0,0)').attr({
  x: 20,
  y: 100,
  w: 10,
  h: 100
});
```

remember, CoffeeScript is all about simplicity and avoiding curly braces and commas...

Comment: except when avoiding curly braces & commas degrades readability. Though it is not the case here, it's easy to cross the line & join the dark side

Comment: Overdoing is never a good thing. My point was that CoffeeScript is something like a 'Python for JS'.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution would be to put your object on one line, as in `.attr({x: 20, y: 100, w: 10, h: 100})`. (Haven't tested it though, but I don't see why it would not work).

While you can sometimes not use the brackets, I prefer to use them in functions calls as I find it more readable.

Comment: Sure, this works. I already have a working code in hand but I'm wondering why compiler gives the error to my second example, and how can I pass an object if I have dozens of elements in it so I have to split in to lines.